# How to align all the text after "where" statement? and How to wrap the text?

Tags: align, vertical-alignment

I am using LateX for the 1st time (just started yesterday). [image]

Can someone please share how do I align everything after the "where" term? I wish to describe each term of the equation.

Also how do I wrap the text? Is there a way to automatically wrap the text to the equal sign? I am currently using `split`

here's the tex code -

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \rho e}{\partial t} = &\text{ Rate of change of total energy e with respect to time. It contains both internal energy} \\&\text{ and kinetic energy}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot (\rho e V) = &\text{ Divergence of convective flux of energy. Accounts for the transport of} \\&\text{ energy through the fluid flow.}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
-\nabla \cdot(pV) = &\text{ Work done on the fluid by the presure forces. It describes the changes} \\&\text{ in the pressure with in the fluid.}
\end{align*}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot (k \nabla T) = &\text{ Represents the heat transfer by conduction in the fluid due to temerature gradient} \\&\text{k is thermal conductivity and T is temp. gradient}
\end{align*}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{align*}
\text{Q} = \text{Heat transfer into the fluid per unit volume, accounting for any external heat sources or sinks.}
\end{align*}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{align*}
\text{W} = \text{ Represents the work done by the viscous forces in the fluid flow}
\end{align*}
\end{flushleft}
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\parbox`'es:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial \rho e}{\partial t}
  &= \parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{Rate of change of total energy e with
    respect to time. It contains both internal energy and kinetic energy}\\
  \nabla \cdot (\rho e V)
  &= \parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{Divergence of convective flux of
    energy. Accounts for the transport of energy through the fluid flow.}\\
  -\nabla \cdot(pV)
  &= \parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{Work done on the fluid by the presure
    forces. It describes the changes  in the pressure with in the fluid.}\\
  \nabla \cdot (k \nabla T)
  &= \parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{Represents the heat transfer by
    conduction in the fluid due to temperature gradient $k$ is thermal
    conductivity and $T$ is temp. gradient.}\\
  Q
  &= \parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{Heat transfer into the fluid per unit
    volume, accounting for any external heat sources or sinks.}\\ 
  W
  &= \parbox[t]{.7\textwidth}{Represents the work done by the viscous
    forces in the fluid flow.}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]